# Error while creating ios expo build fastlane

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

✖ Build failed

iOS build failed:
The "Run fastlane" (https://expo.dev/accounts/aamiryameen901/projects/Yofamous/builds/ad6e0158-dc19-4543-a63e-8e8cdc16987c#run-fastlane) step failed with an unknown error. Refer to the "Xcode logs" (https://expo.dev/accounts/aamiryameen901/projects/Yofamous/builds/ad6e0158-dc19-4543-a63e-8e8cdc16987c#xcode-logs) phase for additional, more detailed logs

Please give me the solution, i'm facing this issue while creating ios build in expo.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hey, when clicking on your link, I cant see the logs. It wants me to login. Can you post your logs another way?